# Missing argument connectionString in Azure iot hub and devices simulators project

Tags: azure, cloud, visual-studio-2017, iot

I have this issue: https://github.com/kentstroker/IoT-Live-2017/issues/4

I'm almost solving so I need two answers:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-live-data-visualization-in-web-apps

In Application settings,  under App settings (in azure portal) whant I put in key/value pairs to ***Azure.IoT.IoTHub.ConnectionString*** (the name or de value key)

**Because I have already tried putting it in various ways and never connects, always back error 500**

Can you help to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kind note to those who ran into **HTTP ERROR 500**:

1. Make sure you are using IoT Hub Connection string, and not the Device Connection string.
2. This has solved my HTTP Error 500 issues.

More info about different connection strings:
[Understand Different Connection Strings in Azure IoT Hub](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/iotdev/2017/05/09/understand-different-connection-strings-in-azure-iot-hub/)